# Nginx Redirect for WooCommerce Checkout Endpoint

Tags: nginx, configuration, woocommerce, url-rewriting, endpoint

I would like to ask how it would be the rewrite rule for nginx for adding to a variable directory at the end of an address a slash. Specificaly i want to solve a 404 error that occurs when i use WooCommerce with nginx - php-fpm.
The slash to be added is at the checkout endpoint and it would look like this

http://xxxx.xx/checkout/xxx?key=wc_order_5702b88b72e77
to rewrite to 
http://xxxx.xx/checkout/xxx/?key=wc_order_5702b88b72e77

where the "xxx" after the /checkout/ is the order number and it is a variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are not the same. As you can see there is an extra slash after the /checkout/xxx so it becomes /checkout/xxx/

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want something like this:

```
server {
    # put this before your locations
    rewrite ^(/checkout/[a-z0-9]+)$ $1/ permanent;
}
```

I assume that the order id contains numbers and lower case characters only. You might want to change this by changing the regex. `0-9` match numbers, `A-Z` uppercase characters and `a-z` lowercase characters.

You can also put the rewrite in a location block to make it more specific.

```
location ~ ^/checkout/[a-z0-9]+$ {
    rewrite ^(/checkout/[a-z0-9]+)$ $1/ permanent;
}
```

Additionally, instead of using the `permanent` flag that permanently redirects requests (301 redirect) you can use the flag `last` which stops processing the current set and the rewritten request is passed once again to find the appropriate location.